# Odd behavior running batch file from windows scheduler

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I wanted to define a scheduled job to backup all SVN repositories every Friday

so I created the following batch file:

```
@echo off
CLS 

SET "source_dir=D:\SVN\Repositories"
SET "backup_dir=D:\SVN_REGULAR_BACKUP"
SET MAX_BACKUPS=3

set DD=%DATE:~7,2%
set MM=%DATE:~4,2%
set YY=%DATE:~12,2%
set YYYY=%DATE:~10,4%
set HH=%TIME:~0,2%
set MN=%TIME:~3,2%

SET "backuptime=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%MN%"

mkdir %backup_dir%\%backuptime%

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir %source_dir% /ad /b') do (
    mkdir %backup_dir%\%backuptime%\%%A
    svnadmin dump %source_dir%\%%A  > %backup_dir%\%backuptime%\%%A\%%A_dump_%backuptime%.svn_dump
)

for /f "skip=%MAX_BACKUPS% delims=" %%A in ('dir %backup_dir% /ad /b /o-d') do rmdir /s /q "%backup_dir%\%%A"
```

and it is working fine, once I execute it , it creates a backup and remove the 3rd old one (exactly as I want)

but when it runs from windows task scheduler, it just creates an empty folder , and deletes the 3rd only one!

for me, it's a very odd behavior, can someone explains what's happening?

Edit (1)

My OS is: Windows 7 Enterprise

when I run the task manually, it results the same (empty folder)

Exported XML for task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2014-07-15T14:02:04.1374691</Date>
    <Author>VF-EG\awahba20</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2014-07-18T23:00:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByWeek>
        <DaysOfWeek>
          <Friday />
        </DaysOfWeek>
        <WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval>
      </ScheduleByWeek>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>VF-EG\awahba20</UserId>
      <LogonType>S4U</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>D:\SVN\backupSVN.bat</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Comment: You say `when I run the task manually, it results the same (empty folder)` so the fault is not with task scheduler, right?

Comment: @foxidrive I mean when I right click on the task and choose run, when I execute the bat file the result is ok.

Comment: Please also confirm that the batch file functions properly when clicked on in explorer or from the cmd prompt.

Comment: @foxidrive yes, it runs properly and does what is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the OS, but this is pretty much the same for everything since W2k.

Check that the scheduled task is set to "Run whether user is logged on or not" and make sure the credentials you enter have administrative right (perhaps not necessary, but will avoid other issues).  You can also check the "Run with highest privileges" and I think that runs the task as the system account.

Does the task work if you right-click > run?

Also if you have Win 7 you can right-click  > "Export..." and then paste that in the question to help out.

Comment: Thank you, OS is windows 7, I exported the task and added it to the Q, I checked "Run whether user is logged on or not" and "Run with highest privileges" with no help, running the task manually leads for same result (empty folder)

Comment: After re-reading I realize that the task is running because the folder is created.  I would have next though of permissions like Alireza stated.  What happens if you run nothing but a hard-coded version of the line `svnadmin dump %source_dir%\%%A  > %backup_dir%\%backuptime%\%%A_dump_%backuptime%.svn_dump` in the batch file and through the scheduled task?

Comment: I created a hard coded batch file with this line only, it finished with status (0X1) , and created an empty dump file (0KB) , and in task history I found: " action "C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe" with return code 1." , what do you think ?

Comment: Can you get that hard-coded line to work straight from a command prompt?  If not, then I think the issue is with the SVN command, not the the batch file or scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation for something like this would be a permission problem: the scheduler tasks running under a less privileged user than the command prompt.
Either escalate the user which the scheduler service runs under, or grant the current user 'modify' permissions on `D:\SVN_REGULAR_BACKUP` and `D:\SVN\Repositories`

Comment: The task runs by the same user (mine) , and I am the creator of "D:\SVN_REGULAR_BACKUP" directory , please check the exported task xml in my edit, it may lead for a hint or something

Comment: Can you enable the task history and check if any errors are logged?

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

Instead of this:

```
SET backuptime="%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%MN%"
```

Double quote the item like the following which doesn't include the double quotes in the variable.
Windows is tolerant of odd double quoting - most of the time... some tools will fail.

```
SET "backuptime=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%MN%"
```

This doesn't use the brief switch, and is redundant code.

```
FOR /F %%A in ('dir %backup_dir% /A:D') do set count=%%A
set /a count=count
set /a count=count-2
```

in fact this is all you need because if there are less than %max_backups% it won't do a thing.

```
for /f "skip=%MAX_BACKUPS% delims=" %%A in ('dir %backup_dir% /ad /b /o-d') do rmdir /s /q "%backup_dir%\%%A"
```

In this section you need the "delims=" if any folders contain spaces or `&` etc.
Your double quoting does need further work though.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir %source_dir% /ad /b') do (
    mkdir %backup_dir%\%backuptime%\%%A
    svnadmin dump %source_dir%\%%A  > %backup_dir%\%backuptime%\%%A_dump_%backuptime%.svn_dump
)
```

Comment: Thank you for all useful comments, I applied them all, but with no luck, running the script from task scheduler still creates an empty folder only, and deletes one old folder

Comment: Is this on a network or a local drive?  By default task scheduler does not have access to a network.

Comment: I configure, schedule, run on a windows server machine which I access through remote desktop, but the script runs locally and access SVN which is installed on same server machine

Comment: I created a hard coded batch file with 1 line that creates a dump for 1 rep. , it finished with status (0X1) , and created an empty dump file (0KB) , and in task history I found: " action "C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe" with return code 1." , what do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same odd behavior, but all that i needed to do was:

In the task scheduler, tab 'Action', double-click on the action and there is a "start in (optional)", I put there the path of my script and it worked!

Hope it help you.